# Can we change the "pling" sound from the chat?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined

It's currently just... ugh, unpleasant. And not like a "ping" at all. Can haz change to normal pling sound from SO?

Comment: It'd be great if the anime & manga site could have someone going 'Kawaii~!" or "Neee~?", more suitably: "Kora!" (Hey!) hahaha ;)

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, all sites that have a chat.stackexchange.com home URL have that noise.

There are userscripts to change it that you can install on your browser (see [StackApps](http://stackapps.com).) or you can mute all sounds from the chatroom and, instead, rely on desktop notifications.

To turn off all sounds in a chatroom, just click the speaker icon next to the chatroom name.

[image: chatspeaker]

Comment: Is that to distinguish them from the "proper" site chats? I think I may just open up a topic on meta.SO...

Comment: @Xeo Only Stack Overflow and Meta Stack Overflow have their own chat servers. All the other sites in the network have their chatrooms hosted on chat.stackexchange.com